# Как менять цену при выборе вариативного товара WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Привет!
Столкнулся вчера с проблемой того, что при выборе вариации товара цена не меняется под названием.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо правильно настроить вариативный товар. Вот [инструкция на английском](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/)

Сначала на странице /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes надо задать какой-то атрибут товара, например, цвет. Потом на той же странице задать значения этого атрибута (красный, синий).

Далее согласно инструкции на странице товара сделать товар вариативным, задать вариации и для каждой из вариаций (красный, синий) указать свои данные, в том числе цену и изображение товара.